# Using a class before it is declared

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes: `Object` and `String`, where `String` extends `Object`. The `Object` class has a method called `toString()` which returns a `String`. However, the compiler tells me that I cannot return an uninitialized type. How do I achieve this?

My code:

```cpp
class Object;
class String;
```

```cpp
class Object {
public:
    String toString() {…} // compiler error because string is undefined, but cannot move it to top.
}

class String : public Object {

}
```

Comment: You may want to return a (smart) pointer to String instead of just String.

Comment: *I have 2 classes: Object and String. String extends Object.* -- Using terms like *extends* and deriving from `Object` -- are you trying to use Java techniques in a C++ program?  If so, I highly recommend not to do this.

Comment: You can achieve that with [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp), but the shown code demonstrates a bad design. Don't forget to finish class definitions with semicolons.

Comment: Move the function body outside the class and put it after `String`'s definition.

Comment: Move the definition of `Object::toString` to after the `String` class definition.

Comment: *The Object class has a method called toString which returns a String* -- This really does look like an attempt at turning C++ into Java.  First, a `toString` method is eerily "Java-esque" in nature, even the function name shouts "Java".  Why not simply return a `std::string` and not  a `String` object?   Second, the "god object" approach, which it seems you are taking, is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Hello guys, I don’t think you are understaanding my goal. I am trying to make a mapping of all of the classes in JNI for a game to cpp for ease of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type needs to be complete (i.e. declared and fully defined) in the function definition, but is permitted to be incomplete (i.e. declared, but not defined) in the non-defining function declaration.

So

```
class String;

class Object {
public:
    inline String toString();
};

class String : public Object { /*...*/ };

inline Object::toString() { /*...*/ }
```

will be fine. If you want to define the `toString` member function in a `.cpp`/`.cc`/... instead of directly in the header, then you have to remove both `inline`. On the other hand the `inline` is required if the function is defined in a shared header file. (It is not needed when directly defining the function inside the class, because that implies an automatic `inline`.)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.